# What would be the best method to pull 2 list (map or set) of Task for merging

Tags: apex, merge

A little background we had a 3rd party develop a vfp that forces reps to fill out a `Task` in a very specific way based on Program(Custom Object related to `Account`) criteria.  Meanwhile these reps are on the phone using a CTI Connector which also creates a `Task` which captures Cisco data.  The objective is to use the `What ID` and `due date` to link the 2 `Task` move over Cisco data from the call `Task` and then delete it.  Once the information is passed over the updated `task` will no longer meet the criteria be pulled into the (`list`, `set`, or `map`).

This is where I am not certain what my approach should be.  I think my data sets below could be wrong.  My root question is what should my Data Set be when comparing the same object?

```
public with sharing class Task_Methods {

public static void callTasks(List<Task> taskList) {

    Set<ID> AccountIDSet = new Set<ID>();
    Map<ID,ID> AccountCallMap = new Map<ID,ID>();
    List<Task> callList = new List<Task>();
    List<Task> tasksToDelete = new List<Task>();
```

Ending DML:

```
}
    }

    update callList;
    delete tasksToDelete;

}

}
```

Made some changes to the Code:

public with sharing class Task_Methods {

```
public static void callTasks(List<Task> taskList) {

    Map<ID,ID> TaskByButton = new Map<ID,ID>();
    Map<ID,ID> TaskByCall = new Map<ID,ID>();
    List<Task> callList = new List<Task>();
    List<Task> tasksToDelete = new List<Task>();

    for (Task tc : [select id, CallDurationInSeconds, CallObject, CallDisposition, CallType, CallAnsweredTime__c, Extension__c, Subject, what.id, ActivityDate from Task where CallType = null AND Program_Task_Type__c != null ]) {
        TaskByButton.put(tc.whatid,tc.id);
    }

    for (Task t : [select id, CallDurationInSeconds, CallObject, CallDisposition, CallType, CallAnsweredTime__c, Extension__c, Subject, what.id, ActivityDate from Task where CallType != null AND Program_Task_Type__c = null ]) 
    {
        TaskByCall.put(t.whatid,t.id);
    }

    for (Task t : taskList) {
        if (TaskByCall.containsKey(t.WhatId)) {
            Task tc = new Task(id=TaskByCall.get(t.whatID));
            if (tc.CallDurationInSeconds == null) tc.CallDurationInSeconds = t.CallDurationInSeconds;
            if (tc.CallObject == null) tc.CallObject = t.CallObject;
            if (tc.CallDisposition == null) tc.CallDisposition = t.CallDisposition;
            if (tc.CallType == null) tc.CallType = t.CallType;
            if (tc.CallAnsweredTime__c == null) tc.CallAnsweredTime__c = t.CallAnsweredTime__c;
            if (tc.Extension__c == null) tc.Extension__c = t.Extension__c;
            callList.add(tc);

            Task dt = new Task(id=t.id);
            tasksToDelete.add(dt);
        }
    }
```

update callList;
        delete tasksToDelete;

```
}
```

}

Comment: Are they filling out the Visualforce task during the same call that is being captured by the CTI system?  Which task gets inserted first?

Comment: Thanks for responding David in this situation the VFP Task is being filled out during the call.  As to which one gets created first is a toss up.  I was thinking that maybe I need to run some form of scheduled apex to run every 5 or 10 minutes on this class.  Is that a possible solution?

Comment: This is what my code looks like now after making some changes.

Comment: Yes you will need scheduled Apex to this.  But there are difficulties.  What's the typical duration between CTI task creation and the VF page task creation?  What happens if the user delays VF completion beyond the next scheduled run?  What happens if the user makes two calls to the same client/opportunity during the duration, how will you decide which tasks belong to which?

Comment: Hello David,  Thanks for responding!  Both should have the same Account as the WhatID and I intend to have the scheduler run every 5 minutes.  As a business process these reps should only be making a call once a day per Account however you and I know that is not always the case.  That is why I am hoping the 5 minutes should catch them and in any situations where there is no answer or voicemails the amount of work is minimal and should take a minute or less to fill out.

Comment: I am also looking into altering the vfp to create the manual task upon initialization however there is a lot of validation I will need to overcome first.

Answer (score 0):

I think your scheduled class should do the following:

- Select all Tasks (both CTI and user-entered) created since the last run.  You should use a single select statement for this, don't use multiple select statements.  You'll need to track the last run date/time in a custom setting.
- Initialize two maps as Map, one for the CTI and one for the user-entered.  The map keys will be a hash of Task.OwnerId + Task.WhatId.  This will help identify correct task pairs.  There will be a problem though if a user 
  calls the same account within the time period.
- Loop through the list and populate the maps based on the task type.
- Perform your merge task functions
- Update the CTI tasks and delete the user-entered tasks.
- Update the custom setting with the current date/time.

So the pseudocode would be something like this:

```
Task_Merge_Settings__c settings = Task_Merge_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults();

List<Task> tasks = [SELECT Extension__c FROM Task WHERE (Type = 'CTI' OR Type = 'User') AND CreatedDate >= settings.Last_Run_Time__c];

Map<String, Task> ctiTasks = new Map<String, Task>();
Map<String, Task> userTasks = new Map<String, Task>();

for (Task t : tasks) {
    if (t.Type == 'CTI') {
        ctiTasks.put(t.OwnerId + t.WhatId);
    } else if (t.Type == 'User') {
        userTasks.put(t.OwnerId + t.WhatId);
    }
}

for (String hash : ctiTasks.keySet()) {
    Task userTask = userTasks.get(hash);
    ctiTasks.get(hash).Extension__c = userTask.Extension__c;
}

update ctiTasks.values();
delete userTasks.values();

settings.Last_Run_Time__c = System.now();
update settings;
```

Comment: Thanks David I will take your suggestions and attempt to implement.